# How to control the output rating of Raspberry Pi Pico Micro Python

Tags: python, pi-pico

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi community and need to power a 1v motor however, I can not figure out how to output such power.

Here is all of ,my code if you need it:

```
from machine 
import Pin
import time

led=Pin(25,Pin.OUT)
Motor=Pin(15,Pin.OUT)
print("working!")
for i in range (3):
    Motor.value(1)
    led.value(1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Motor.value(0)
    led.value(0)
    time.sleep(1)
    
Motor.value(0)
led.value(0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Perhaps you could edit more detail `into your question` and describe what kit you are using and what you are trying to achieve.  It seems more like an electronics question at the moment.

Comment: I have read that it is possible to increase the output using software, but I could never find out how.

Comment: If you mean adjusting the voltage of a GPIO pin, that doesn't seem possible. [You can only control on and off](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=29306), though that implies you can program a [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the output power of the Pi, however you can turn it on or off and even read its current state. What you want is a MOSFET to drive the motor. This is a sample circuit that you can use. The 12V can be whatever your motor needs. It is important that the grounds be connected and that motor is powered by a external power supply, not the Pi. This simple circuit will allow you to control the motor's speed by PWMing the output pin. Just a note, this inverts the signal so A high on the output turns on the MOSFET pulling the output low. You can skip the diode if you use a MOSFET with an appropriate UIS (valanch) rating. Hopefully this answers your question.
[image]